# myfaces -- duplicate rendering

Tags: jsf

I am using myfaces 1.2 with trinidad and tomahawk.  I have 1 view xhtml that re-displays on a claim search (the div section with the results uses EL to only display if there are results).

On a 2nd submission, it appears that some HTML components display a 2nd time.  For example, i'm using a html table to render a grid.  I am not using any JSF component tags to render the table, it's straightup table, tr, td.

Is there a reason why this occurs, can I not mix HTML tags in xhtml or JSF (without f:verbatim)?  If so, why not?  If not, any hints on what isn't properly configured?  Should I use something other than xhtml?